# Почему не выполняется код

Tags: extension

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*"}, function reloadb() {
    window.document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')[5].click();  // BUTTON NEWEST
 });
 setInterval(reloadb, 5000);
```

Почему не работает код? Если убрать `chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*"},` то код работать будет, но мне нужно что бы эта часть кода выполнялось на конкретном сайте. Расширение перезагружает страницу, если находит нужную ссылку отправляет в форму поиска на другой сайт. Поэтому код для каждого сайта должен быть свой. На всякий случай размещу содержимое файла manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "BountySkins",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
     "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*",
     "*://aaaaaaaaaa.net/*"

   ],
      "js": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "content.js"]


    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код содержит банальные ошибки. Если просто их тупо исправить, то код получится таким

```
function reloadb() {
  window.document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')[5].click();  // BUTTON NEWEST
}

chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*"}, reloadb);
setInterval(reloadb, 5000);
```

или, если обернуть в замыкание

```
(function() {
  var reloadb = function() {
    window.document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')[5].click();  // BUTTON NEWEST
  };
  chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*"}, reloadb);
  setInterval(reloadb, 5000);
})();
```

Но у меня вызывает сомнение необходимость вызова `setInterval`. И если я прав, то тогда все превращается в такой вызов

```
chrome.tabs.query({url: "*://xxxxxxxxxx.com/*"}, function() {
  window.document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item')[5].click();  // BUTTON NEWEST
});
```

Comment: спасибо. Я сделал как сказали, но все ровно не работает Uncaught TypeError: `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined` в строке с url ошибка. Указываю ссылку так же как и в манифесте

Comment: Понял, нельзя использовать tabs в контент скрипте, нужно использовать chrome.runtime